# Proofs on unconventional computing

Tags: soft-question, natural-computing

Are there any interesting proofs on unconventional computing? When reading on the topic I most often see soft analysis – like following paragraph from Wikipedia ([Natural computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_computation)):

> Swarm intelligence,[12] sometimes referred to as collective
>   intelligence, is defined as the problem solving behavior that emerges
>   from the interaction of individual agents (e.g., bacteria, ants,
>   termites, bees, spiders, fish, birds) which communicate with other
>   agents by acting on their local environments.

Instead of soft analysis – are there any formal (and important) results in the topic?

Answer (score 8):

A recent and interesting attempt to model flocking behavior is [Bernard Chazelle's work](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs.html) (see the four most recent papers (as of Mar 2012). He's also [running a summer school](http://www.sns.ias.edu/pitp/) on computation and biology at the Institute for Advanced Science.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you this survey/introduction paper (but perhaps you alredy read it):

[Unconventional computing: a short introduction](http://www.cs.ubbcluj.ro/~studia-i/2009-1/08-Oltean.pdf) by M. Oltean (2009).

It is a little bit funny (see for example the *"Price"* column in the comparison table) ... however the references at the bottom can lead you to other relevant papers.

I'm not an expert but searching papers on other subjects I sometimes found titles about the *"DNA computing" model*, so - if you classify Quantum Computing conventional computing :-) - I think it is one of the most studied model, and there are many results out there (see for example "[A Robust DNA Computation Model that Captures PSPACE](http://cs.roosevelt.edu/~wolpert/papers/DW-IJFCS.ps)").

I'm curious to see other answers about other weird models/results.

**EDIT:** I was missing a "must": Scott Aaronson's "[NP-Complete Problems and Physical Reality](http://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/npcomplete.pdf)" (2005). There is also a PowerPoint presentation ... but unfortunately no video (Scott's presentations are great, see for example a small easy introduction on [(un)conventional??? quantum computing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SczraSQE3MY) :-)

Comment: I think this is what you actually meant to link to: http://www.cs.ubbcluj.ro/~studia-i/2009-1/08-Oltean.pdf

Answer (score 3):

There are also continuous time and analog computation models: [Survey on Continuous Time Computation](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.3117v1.pdf), [Polynomial differential equation model](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0885064X07000246).

Answer (score 2):

[Population protocols.](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~ruppert/papers/pop-survey.pdf)

The model is intuitively explained as being inspired by how a flock of birds behaves and processes information.